# I need to prove that $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$ for discrete random variables but just using the definition of expected value

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

First of all i want to say that i know (and i checked) other posts that talks of the same subject, but i'm trying a different perspective, and that's why i'm writing this topic.

Well, i need to prove that $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$, but the only thing i know is that $$E(X) = \sum_{i}^{n} x_i P(X=x_i),$$ and $$E(Y) = \sum_{i}^{n} y_i P(Y=y_i).$$ Some answers i saw on related topics uses an identity that don't know yet, that is: $E(X+Y) = \sum_{i,j}^{n} (x_i + y_i) p_{ij},$ and i'm trying something like this:

$$E(X) + E(Y) = \sum_{i}^{n} x_i P(X=x_i) + \sum_{i}^{n} y_i P(Y=y_i) = \sum_{i}^{n} x_i P(X=x_i) + y_i P(Y=y_i) .$$

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are equally distribuited, we can say that $P(X=x_i) = P(Y=y_i)$. Naming $P(X=x_i) = P(Z=z_i)$, with $Z = x+y$ and rewriting:

$$\sum_{i}^{n} x_i P(X=x_i) + y_i P(Y=y_i) = \sum_{i}^{n} (x_i + y_i) P(Z=x_i).$$

I'm not shure that i can say that $\sum_{i}^{n} (x_i + y_i) P(Z=x_i) = E(X+Y)$ and that's  one of my doubts. The other is: is this proceeding correct?

Comment: **Key:** By the Law of Total Probability: $\mathsf P(X=x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^m \mathsf P(X=x_i, Y=y_j)$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @GrahamKemp! I thought that only using the definitions of the expected value of the RV was sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ takes $n$ values $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, and $Y$ takes $m$ values $\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[X+Y]&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m(x_i+y_j)\mathsf{P}(X=x_i,Y=y_j) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m x_i\mathsf{P}(X=x_i,Y=y_j) \\
&\quad+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m y_j\mathsf{P}(X=x_i,Y=y_j) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\mathsf{P}(X=x_i)+\sum_{j=1}^m y_j\mathsf{P}(Y=y_j) \\
&=\mathsf{E}X+\mathsf{E}Y.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration @d.k.o. Could you tell me where did i go wrong in my attempt?

Comment: @GabrielParizoto You last equation is incorrect.